# Jinja2/Flask, I Can't get a dynamic value from a checkbox

Tags: python, web, flask, jinja2

So i have this html

```
<label class="continer">Empresa Confidencial
     {% if proyecto.10 == 1 %}
     <input type="checkbox" id="confidencial" name="confidencial" value="1" checked>
     {% else  %}
     <input type="checkbox" id="confidencial" name="confidencial" value="0">
     {% endif %}
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

proyect.py

```
def editar_(confidencial,estado,id):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('UPDATE proyecto set EMPRESA_CONFIDENCIAL=%s,estado=%s where PK_PROYECTO=%s', (confidencial,estado, id,))
    mysql.connection.commit()
```

adminviews.py

```
@app.route("/editar", methods=["POST"])
def editar():
    print('.................................................................................')
    id = request.form['id']
    estado = request.form.get('estado') 
    confidencial = request.form.get('confidencial')
    print(id,str(estado), str(confidencial))
    pr.editar_(confidencial,estado,id)
    return redirect(url_for('empresasT'))
```

And i need to get the value `"1"` or `"0"` to send it to the database, the problem is that when i run the code, without the `"confidencial"` in `proyect.py` and `adminvie.py`, it runs and make changes in the database, but when i try again with the `"confidencial"`, and make a change in the `checkbox`, if the checkbox is checked and i unchecked it the value is none, but if i leave it checked, the value is the one by default, the console it says that the value is null, `MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'EMPRESA_CONFIDENCIAL' cannot be null")`, the process is not getting the value `"1"` or `"0"` from the `checkbox` after the modification, but the other values that i got like id and estado does, i think is the `if` statement, how can i get the value from the `checkbox` in the html using the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add checked to both the checkboxes.

Comment: mmm no that didnt work, cause i need to capture the value 1 or 0 when its changed, but when i run it, and use the button to submit the changes, the value set as "none", but if i dont make a change in the checkbox, it stays as default

Comment: Did you restart the server and reloaded the page cause sometimes it won't update and you don't need value to be 1 or 0 since checked is already a Boolean

Comment: yeah i restart the server and reload with shift+f5, i'll try to get the checked value, and then transform it to 1 or 0, cause the guy who did the database set it as 1 or 0...

Answer (score 0):

As I investigated, flask treats checkboxes the same as django, so i add this line in my adminviews.py code

```
 if confidencial is None:
    confidencial = "0"
```

making that always the checkbox turn off, the value will be none, but for practical uses, i modify it inside the method